# SSL Server-side certificate on client computer?

Tags: wcf, ssl

There is a server with WCF client, which periodically initiates communications over internet with many WCF services installed on our clients computers. WCF services and WCF clients are hosted in Windows Service, current binding is basicHttpBinding.

Communication has to be over https with mutual authentication. Company ordered SSL certificate but it is not clear if this certificate can be installed on clients computers (because WCF service is there) without exposing a private key. Binding can be basicHttpBinding or wcHttpBinding with transport or message security but using certificates.

Is it possible to install service-side certificate on client computers and client-side certificate on our server? Should this architecture be re-worked so WCF service is on our server or it is possible to secure somehow this current solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Each* computer involved requires it's *own* certificate. A certificate value for authentication relies on the *uniqueness* of the private key. The private key never leaves the host machine, and the certificate can be used to authenticate said machine (because is the only one in the world that posses that private key). As soon as you start distributing copies of a private key, security is pretty much compromised.

Normally such deployment rely on PKI infrastructure which can create certificates on-demand and sign them with a trusted key.

What product/protocol the certificates are used for is irrelevant. What kind of WCF HTTP binding you use it maters not.

Comment: It does not seem feasible to create a certificate for every computer since there could be thousands of them.

Comment: @user6431152: that's exactly why a PKI was recommended which has no problems of dealing with thousands of certificates.